# Group by Only when no NULL Values are present on another Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following View

[image]

and would like to run a query on it where it will group by ID only for ID's where UserCerId is not null..

the result should be

```
ID, Title,             Description,            createdAt, updatedAt
1,  This is the title, Some Job description 11, ..., ...
2,  This is the title, Some Job description 12, ..., ...
3,  This is the title, Some Job description 13, ..., ...
```

4 and 5 should not be listed because there is a null there

I have something like

```
Select id, title, description, UserId, createdAt, updatedAt from ViewName
Group By id
```

much appreciated.

Comment: Generally you want to include all columns in the `select` also in the `group by` that are not used as aggregates (`count`, `max`, ...) That syntax only works in `mysql` and should be avoided in most cases.  Which values should you take from the other columns?  And if you don't want `null` values, use either `having` or `not exists`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the condition in the HAVING clause:

```
select v.id, v.title, v.description, v.UserId, v.createdAt, v.updatedAt, min(usercerid) usercerid
from ViewName v
group by v.id, v.title, v.description, v.UserId, v.createdAt, v.updatedAt
having sum(v.usercerid is null) = 0
```

You must group by all the columns that you select.
I used `min(usercerid)` as the output column although it's not obvious that you want it even in the results. If you don't need it remove it.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja MIN/MAX does not consider NULL do be values.. They are skipped not removed..

Comment: yeah ive deleted my comment agreed it doesnt show up/count nulls in min/max etc. I din see earlier that the Op needs to check the nulls in a group too

Comment: *"You must group by all the columns that you select."* Yes before SQL 1999 standard you had indeed have to do that.. But MySQL 5.7.5+ when sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled supports SQL 1999+ standards optional feature which is called functional dependency,,, Meaning if a column has a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key for this example we assume id column to have a PRIMARY KEY then a query like `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id` becomes valid..

Comment: @RaymondNijland since the result of `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id` is ambiguous in any case and not guaranteed in any part of the documentation, the *rule* remains the same.

Comment: *"since the result of SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY id is ambiguous in any case and not guaranteed in any part of the documentation, the rule remains the same."*  Sorry but you are wrong.. Read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and [Detection of Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) with care..  This is in fact a guaranteed deterministic resultset the MySQL manual explain it plus functional dependecy is defined in the SQL 1999 standards as well..

Comment: @RaymondNijland read from the link you posted: "In this case, the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are **nondeterministic**, which is probably not what you want. "

Comment: You read the wrong part and qouted from the part when sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is **disabled**... above that you find and read this statement with care -> SQL:1999 and later permits such nonaggregates per optional feature T301 if they are functionally dependent on GROUP BY columns: If such a relationship exists between name and custid, the query is legal. This would be the case, for example, were custid a primary key of customers.   ....

Comment: I did not say that the query is not *legal*. I said: *You must group by all the columns that you select* and I insist on that because although MySql allows to break this rule it does not mean that it is logically correct.

Comment: well mine statement was there that you does always have to group by on every column.. *"although MySql allows to break this rule it does not mean that it is logically correct."* Also MySQL does not break this rules it is in fact a ANSi/ISO SQL standard, functionally dependency is defined in SQL 1999+ ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland `GROUP BY id` will cause an error in **any** MySQL version with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, since `id` is not unique.

Comment: Well, I dont know much about the documentation but i guess this should go by semantics of data not by syntax of group by query. if i have a unique id/ single row on each id then group by id isnt wrong without aggregates

Comment: @PaulSpiegel *"GROUP BY id will cause an error in any MySQL version with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, since id is not unique. '* ***Yes i know how that works and yes i agree in this case with this data you should get a error***.. Mine comments where meant in general as reaction on *"You must group by all the columns that you select."* which is not always the case as functionally dependency is a valid thing in MySQL and SQL standards..  i think mine comments where heavy misread/misunderstood..

Comment: @Raymond group by all columns isnt mandatory at all occasions where its not needed the point is. eg what if the table has 100 columns and i want to use group by but i have unique id here i can use group by id

Answer (score -1):

Just put a where clause before group by to have only non null values as by the sequence of execution of an sql query all the nulls usercertid will be removed via where (as it doesnt matter to which id it belongs since it is null ) and then grouping will be done via group by.

```
Select id, title, description, UserId, 
createdAt, updatedAt from ViewName 
vn
where vn.UserCertId is not NULL GROUP 
 BY id, vn.title, vn.description, vn.UserId, 
vn.createdAt, vn.updatedAt;
```

or else if you just want to show non nulls then put an aggregate max() or min on column UserCertiId or if you also want  to check for nulls then in having use having sum(UserCid is Null) =0 as in one of the answers below.

Comment: it will still return id 4, 5 because they have UserCertId that are not null

Comment: check now ive updated your table structure was different from the image so had a typo earlier

Answer (score -1):

For me the solution is to exclude all id who have at least one NULL value on UserCertId

```
Select id, title, description, UserId, createdAt, updatedAt from ViewName
WHERE id NOT IN ( Select DISTINCT id from ViewName WHERE UserCertId IS NULL)
Group By id, title, description, UserId, createdAt, updatedAt
```

Edited for full Group By

Comment: This is generally invalid GROUP BY usage.. ANSI/ISO SQL 1999+ standard might support this query by functional dependecy which MySQL 5.7.5+ supports when sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is enabled otherwise this query is invalid SQL..